# How to change VB6 COM dll assembly Versions?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, com, vb6

I using a myDll.dll VB6 dll that I am registering using regsvr32.

In visual studio when I try to reference it from my C# project using the "add reference" functionality, I can see it in the COM tab and it says it's version is 8.0.
However from Windows I can see that it's file version is 1.0.121.

I assume 8.0 is the assembly version and 1.0.121 is the file version.

I would like to change 8.0 to 9.0.

Using Visual Basic 6, I open the dll project
Project -> myDll properties -> Make

And I can see that I can change 1.0.121, however I can't see anywhere where to change 8.0.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Comment: It is the type library version.  You cannot set it directly, it is affected by the Compatibility setting.  The major version number is incremented when you select Project compatibility, minor version is increment when you select Binary compatibility.  If you've got 8.0 then you surely already have Project compatibility selected.  So just make a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one for @HansPassant but I think that the 8.0 you are seeing refers to the COM version in the registry not the file/assembly version of the component.

VB6 creates a new COM version whenever a change is made that breaks compatability with the previous version e.g. removing a property.

If you download OLEView and browse to your component name you will probably see somthing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the interface, or type library version.  COM interfaces have an ID consisting of a UUID and a Version.  When you make a non-breaking change such as adding a new Property, the Major part of this version number is incremented.

[Levels of Binary Version Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242136%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Breaking binary compatibility is entirely different, and results in new class ID and type library ID values.  When you do this you really should create a new name for the Project, and thus the DLL itself.